# Redirect awk output to a different folder

Tags: bash, awk

I am using an awk command to split certficates from a `secretData.file`. I need to store these split certificates (`filename`) into a different folder called server/certs. I am doing so using this command

```
export CERT_PATH='/server/certs'
awk '/#/{fileName=$0;next}{print fileName > $CERT_PATH/fileName;}' secretData.file
```

The error says :

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "CERT_PATH"
```

I also tried this :

```
awk '/#/{fileName=$0;next}{print fileName > '$CERT_PATH'/fileName;}' secretData.file
```

But It gives a different error:

```
awk: division by zero
```

What the issue could be? is there any other way I could do this? I was able to find solutions to save the awk output to a different folder's file but here the case is a little different.

Comment: `print ENVIRON["CERT_PATH"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Use awk's `-v` option to pass the shell variable to awk:

```bash
awk -v cert_path="$CERT_PATH"  '/#/{fileName=$0;next}{print fileName > cert_path "/fileName";}' secretData.file
```

I also fixed the quoting in the redirection it should be `print fileName > cert_path "/fileName";`

Comment: Gives a Syntax error. I fixed it using mv command. But Thanks for help.